# Calculate the number of elements in a foreach statement

Tags: c#, foreach, count, sum

```
@foreach (var type in Model.GetPeople())
{
    var peopleGroup1 = persons.First();
    var category = new category { Id = person.CategoryId,;

    etc...
}
```

How do I count the number of 'types' in the foreach statement?

Comment: `Model.GetPeople().Count`?

Comment: It's really not clear what difficulties you had, the straightforward approach (without LINQ) would be a simple counter variable which you increase in the `foreach`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`IEnumerable<T>` has a [`Count()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338038%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) extension:

```
var people = Model.GetPeople();
var count = people.Count();
```

Depending on the specific type it has already  a `Count` property:

```
count = people.Count;
```

This is available for every type implementing `ICollection` or `ICollection<T>` , but not for `IQueryable<T>`. An array has a `Length` property.

Comment: If that solves the question  my first question to OP is why he doesn't use a variable to count it in the `foreach`. You are enumerating the people twice, once in the `foreach` and again in `Count` (if it's not a list or array).

Comment: Good question. One possible answer: He needs the count before the loop is complete...

Comment: Or may be unaware of `Count`.

Comment: Anyhow: If the OP tells us more about his exact problem we may can help better. At the moment there is "some guessing" involved...

Comment: @TimSchmelter: Thanks for the improvement.

Answer (score 3):

to get count, no need to travers foreach loop. you just directly get count though

```
Model.GetPeople().Count
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int count = 0;
foreach (var type in Model.GetPeople())
{
    count++;
    var peopleGroup1 = persons.First();
    var category = new category { Id = person.CategoryId,;
    etc...
}
```